# Throwing Meteor.Error always returns 403 in error.error

Tags: meteor, error-handling, throw

For some reason, in my web app when I `throw new Meteor.Error('my-reason', 'Full details')`, in the client callback, `error.error` evaluates to 403 instead of "my-reason." So I did a quick test in a separate folder:

```
if Meteor.isClient
  Template.stuff.events
    'click .throw': ->
      Meteor.call 'throwError', 'dummy data', (error, result) ->
        console.log error.error

if Meteor.isServer
  Meteor.methods
    throwError: (str) ->
      throw new Meteor.Error 'work-please', 'Please work.'
```

Sure enough, it works great, and `error.error` is "work-please." So why, in my web app I'm developing, does `error.error` eval to 403?? Relevant snippets from said web app:

### Server:

```
createSeller: (userData) ->
  check userData,
    username: String
    email: String
    password: String
    profile: Match.Optional Match.ObjectIncluding({accountType: String})

  newUserId = Accounts.createUser
    username: userData.username
    email: userData.email
    password: userData.password
    profile:
      accountType: 'seller'

  if newUserId # successfully made new user
    Accounts.sendVerificationEmail newUserId
    return { success: true }
  else
    throw new Meteor.Error 'user-exists', 'User already exists.'
```

### Client:

```
Meteor.call 'createSeller', newUser, (error, result) ->
  Session.set 'creatingUser', false
  console.log error.error
```

Comment: Blind shot, but isn't it `error.reason`?

Comment: No, `error.reason` is the full plain English description (in this case, "User already exists."). `error.error` is the short form ("user-exists").

Comment: 403 is default, if you want some other number you should do like : throw new Meteor.Error( 500, 'User already exists' );

Comment: @Sindis You should read the question again and see that I'm already throwing a custom error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the issue is that the error is thrown, not returned, from the call to `Accounts.createUser`, and *that* error, not the error you're manually creating, is what's being sent back to the client.  In other words, you're never even reaching

```
else
    throw new Meteor.Error 'user-exists', 'User already exists.'
```

because execution has stopped before you reach that point.

I think you can work around this by catching the error out of the `Accounts.createUser` call:

```
try { 
newUserId = Accounts.createUser
    username: userData.username
    email: userData.email
    password: userData.password
    profile:
      accountType: 'seller'
} catch (err) { 
  throw new Meteor.Error 'user-exists', 'User already exists.'
}

// If you get to here you know there wasn't an error so no need for if statement
Accounts.sendVerificationEmail newUserId
return { success: true }
```